# Delta function reports 0 when the data series disappears

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm currently using this PromQL query to detect issues with Kubernetes apiservers:

```
delta(sum(up{job="kubernetes-apiservers"}) by (cluster)[3h:1m])
```

The problem I have is that when the whole cluster goes down the `up` metric for those apiservers disappears and `delta` does not show the change, it stays flat.

Is there way to use one query for when the `count` of apiservers goes down and when they all disappear?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query:

> sum(absent_over_time(up{job="kubernetes-apiservers"}[5m])) by
> (cluster)

This uses the absent_over_time() function to calculate the duration for which the up metric is absent for each cluster over the past 5 minutes. You can set up an alert rule in Prometheus to trigger when the absence duration exceeds a certain threshold, indicating that all targets in a cluster have gone down.

Comment: If this helped answer your question, please mark this as the answer. thanks!